# openmp on minwg with posix-threads

Tags: pthreads, mingw, openmp

I noticed that openmp can work with both posix-thread and win32-thread variants of mingw-64.

I would like to use posix-thread version with openmp in mingw. However, in the wiki page of Qt the following notice is written:

> posix (built upon MinGW-w64’s winpthreads): Performance degradation in specific scenarios. C++11 functionality is significantly slower than native Win32 implementation or even MSVS2012’s implementation (http://qt-project.org/wiki/MinGW-64-bit)

My question is: Do the same performance problems exist with openmp implementation with winpthreads? Would it be better if chose win32threads in mingw to work with openmp?

Comment: I'd rather download both variants of toolchain and build a test application with them in order to profile it.

Comment: This is a good question.  I have wondered the same thing.

Comment: The libgomp implementation of openmp provided with gcc requires pthreads which for windows is layered on Windows threads, thus the potential performance deficit.  Libgomp for windows is missing some functionality and is not enabled by default although present in most packaged builds.  Mingw builds using proprietary closed source openmp based directly on Windows threads appear to violate gcc license terms.